# Problemas com filtrar um comparativo de datas em Django

Tags: python, django

Tenho um backend em Django e estou querendo fazer um filtro que compare o valor de duas colunas de datas e filtrar caso uma seja maior que a outra.

Exemplo:

**Código como seria em SQL**

```
SELECT id, data_vencimento, data_entrega
FROM justificativaentrega ju
WHERE data_vencimento < data_entrega;
```

**Minha model**

```
class JustificativaEntrega(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    data_vencimento = models.DateField()
    data_entrega = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Um detalhe é a coluna data_entrega não fica *null* ou *blank*, quando não tem um valor preenchido ele fica como '0001-01-01', então sempre tem algum valor nela. O mesmo vale para a coluna data_vencimento. Seria como se ouvesse `defualt=datetime.date(1,1,1)`.

Tentei usar o `from django.db.models import Q` dessa seguinte forma:

```
JustificativaEntrega.objects.filter(data_entrega__lte=~Q(data_vencimento=date(1,1,1)))
```

Porém não trouxe nenhum resultado.

Comment: Encontrei uma forma de fazer: 
`JustificativaEntrega.objects.filter(data_vencimento__lt=F('data_entrega'))`